# Passing object array list between fragments in Android development

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass arraylist between fragments in Android development. This is the part where I tried to pass Transaction array list to another fragment:

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

                case R.id.expenses:
                    final ExpenseActivity expenseFragment = new ExpenseActivity();
                    new GetAllTransactionAsyncTask(
                            new GetAllTransactionAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    FragmentTransaction expsenseTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    //bundle.putParcelableArrayList("transactionlist", GetAllTransactionAsyncTask.allTransaction);
                                    //bundle.putString("transactionlist", GetAllTransactionAsyncTask.allTransaction);
                                    expenseFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                    expsenseTransaction.replace(R.id.frame,expenseFragment);
                                    expsenseTransaction.commit();
                                }
                            }).execute(session_accountID);


                    return true;
}
```

The `GetAllTransactionAsyncTask.allTransaction`will return a Transaction array list. As for my transaction entity class, I implemented Serializable:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Transaction implements Serializable{
...
}
```

I not sure how do I actually pass an object array list between fragments. I commented out the two lines as they are incompatible type.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try it   bundle.putParcelableArrayList("transactionlist", GetAllTransactionAsyncTask.allTransaction); then get receive it

Comment: I did it but it is incompatible. That's why I am commenting out that line :)

Comment: add parceable plug in your android studio

Comment: Add your Transaction class in an arraylist like this ArrayList<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>(); and then pass it via bundle, new Bundle().putSerializable("Key", transactionList);

Comment: @karthikvishnukumar Sorry but how do I retrieve it at the destination fragment?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Transaction> transactionList = new ArrayList<>();
```

pass the transactionList to the bundle

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("key", transactionList);
```

and in the receiving fragment

```
ArrayList<Transaction> transactionList = (ArrayList<Transaction>)getArguments().getSerializable("key");
```

NOTE: to pass your bean class via bundle you have to implement serializable i.e

YourBeanClass implements Serializable

Answer (score 4):

add this gradle in your `build.gradle` `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'`

```
String str = new Gson().toJson(arrayList);
bundle.putStrin("str",str);
```

and destination fragemnt

```
String str = bundle.getString("str");

arrayList = new Gson().fromJson(str,ArrayList.class);
```

Comment: After I changed it to "Bundle bundle = getArgument()" in destination fragment, I am getting this error message: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to Entity.Transaction

Answer (score 1):

1.You can either pass it by converting into json as specified by @Bhupat.

2.Another way is you make your Transaction class parcelable and the use

```
 b.putParcelableArrayList("list",your_list);
```

for getting  list

```
your_list = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("list");
```

EDIT
you have too sepcigy type token for getting it back

```
 transactionlist = new Gson().fromJson(str,  new TypeToken<List<type of the list passed>>);
```

In your case  `new TypeToken<List<Transaction>>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `Serializable`, you should make your Transaction class implement `Parcelable`. Parcelable is the fastest serialization mechanism you can use on Android, it's faster than Serializable or JSON transformation and uses less memory.