# How to store Array list in shared preferences and access in another fragment

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I want to save this array list data in sharedpreferences and access that data in another fragment .Please Give me suggestion

Array list content given bellow

```
public String productname;
public String productunit;
public String productquantity;
public String productprice;
public String productdiscount;
```

Comment: Serialize the ArrayList using gson then save that data. Another option is to pass these data in a bundle to the fragment.

Comment: *I want to save this array list data in sharedpreferences*. it is  bad idea. instance pass the `arralist` `object` using bundle. Refer Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909061/passing-object-array-list-between-fragments-in-android-development

Comment: best way send data in Argument or otherwise save data as json string in sharedpreferences,

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution,
Step 1: Create a class like

> SharedPreference

```
public static final String FAVORITES = "PRODUCTS";
private SharedPreferences settings;
private Editor editor;

public SharedPreference() {
    super();
}
```

Now code to save ArrayList

> ```
>  public void saveArrayList(Context context, List<String> unread_ids) {
>     settings = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.KEY_PREFS_NAME,
>             Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
>     editor = settings.edit();
>     Gson gson = new Gson();
>     String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(unread_ids);
>     editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
>     editor.apply();
> }
> ```

Now code to get saved Arraylist

```
public ArrayList<String> getSavedList(Context context) {
    // SharedPreferences settings;
    List<String> unReadId;

    settings = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.KEY_PREFS_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
        String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, "");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,
                String[].class);

        unReadId = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
        unReadId = new ArrayList<>(unReadId);

    } else {
        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    return (ArrayList<String>) unReadId;
}
```

Code to save list:

```
sharedPreferences.saveArrayList(context, <YOUR LIST NAME>);
```

Now code to get your Arraylist in other Fragment

```
<LIST NAME> = sharedPreference.getSavedList(getActivity());
```

Before get and save array list you have to declare "sharedPreference" and create its object.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: will you please explain properly ...i am not getting your code. will you please share whole file

Comment: Hi, @anupdabadgavakar, here is project to save arraylist and use later. Link :https://github.com/Sanwal13/SaveArrayInShdPrefs

Comment: @anupdabadgavakar If this helps you, then accepts the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this before Please check this code

```
private List<String> list; /// adding checked items to list
```

inside your `OnCreate()` add this line

```
list = new ArrayList<>(); /// checked items list
```

and to get array from model and store it local please use next.

```
int searchListLength = items.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {
            if (items.get(i).isChecked()) {
                items.get(i).getId();
                Log.d("listitem", String.valueOf("id=" + items.get(i).getId()));
                list.add("id=" + items.get(i).getId());
            }
        }
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : list) {
            stringBuilder.append(s);
            stringBuilder.append("&");
        }

  SharedPreferences notif_array = getSharedPreferences("items_array", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor_notaif = notif_array.edit();
            editor_notaif.putString("id", stringBuilder.toString());
            editor_notaif.apply();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Filtered_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Inside your another activity / fragment

private String new_result;

```
SharedPreferences notif_array = getSharedPreferences("items_array", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        new_result = notif_array.getString("id", null);
```